# What is the opposite of 'parse'?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, semantics, naming

I have a function, parseQuery, that parses a SQL query into an abstract representation of that query.

I'm about to write a function that takes an abstract representation of a query and returns a SQL query string.

What should I call the second function?

Comment: Stringify? JSON class uses this terminology. [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and for the opposite [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I think the verb you want is 'compose'.

Comment: @Joel : http://twitter.com/shanselman/status/5024768993

Comment: I mean, coming back a year later I'd even answer 'assemble' as a better opposite, or 'build' as a better function name.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't check the dates on this... SO question necromancy!

Comment: err.. why not ToString() ? Seems to be the standard set by the likes of Int32, etc

Comment: made my previous comment before seeing that the question was language-agnostic. ToString() seems to be the accepted standard by .NET

Comment: It's now worth 140 (12/17/2014); I think it's a useful answer so I up-voted it, but certainly it's not the equivalent of a complex program; of course a word like this is more "ageless" than certain programming technologies

Answer (score 78):

The opposite of **parse** is **serialize**

Comment: This may be the most useful answer from my perspective.

Comment: What about 'deserialize'?

Answer (score 32):

In compiler terminology, the opposite is "unparse". Specifically, parsing turns a stream of tokens into abstract syntax trees, while unparsing turns abstract syntax trees into a stream of tokens.

Comment: Like _to uncrash a car_ ...

Answer (score 31):

Compose? When parsing a query you break it into its constituent parts (tokens, etc.), the reverse would be composing the parts into a string query.

Answer (score 21):

To complement your existing naming, **composeQuery** looks best.

But in the general case, the opposite of parse is **ǝsɹɐd**

Comment: I think that's the inverse, the opposite would be esrap

Comment: @agusgambina: actually, this makes sense... Think about Bourne shell : if...fi case...esac

Answer (score 20):

I would use one of these:

- ToString()
- ToSQL()
- Render()

Answer (score 17):

I think "serialize" is probably the word you want. It means to produce a textual representation of data that can be exported (and imported) from the program.

Comment: Serialize can just as easily mean a binary representation.

Comment: True. Parsimg is all about fading in external data, and serialization is all about producing data for external uses. The format produced isn't required to be text, but often is.

Comment: Apparently my iPod's keyboard is getting the better of me. That's supposed to be "parsing" and "reading".

Answer (score 15):

The antonym of 'analyze' is 'synthesize'.

Comment: synthesize. good choice.

Answer (score 13):

ToQueryString()

Answer (score 12):

Definitely Render.

Answer (score 10):

I would call it constructQuery.

Comment: That sounds almost perfect. That is what would be happening. He would be collecting data that could be "put into words". He would "construct" a query.

Answer (score 10):

generate or emit, possibly.

Comment: I agree. rfc7159 (JSON), in sections 9 and 10 define "Parser" and "Generator" as opposites.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add some stuff.

Surely parse is a two way word.

You can parse an abstract into a query.

You can parse a query into an abstract.

The question should be, what do you name the latter part of the method, and because in this instance you're parsing an abstract to make a query you'd call it `parseAbstract`.

To answer the question, parsing has no opposite.

Answer (score 9):

generateQuery, possibly? createQuery?

Answer (score 8):

Take your pick

- Generate
- Dump
- Serialize
- Emit

They each have slightly different connotations.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [prettyPrintQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint)?

Answer (score 7):

compose, construct, generate, render,condense, reduce, toSQL, toString depending on the nature of the class and its related operators

Answer (score 6):

A traditional compiler has two parts:  a parser and a code generator.

So you could call it "Generate".   Of course, it's a little bit different here because the compiler isn't writing source code.  (unless it's a precompiler).

Answer (score 5):

Possibly Format(). or ToSQL() in your instance?

Answer (score 5):

unParse()?  Just kidding, I would go with toQueryString()

Answer (score 4):

flatten?

The parsed query object perhaps represents a condition hierarchy, which you are "flattening" back into a 1 dimensional string.

But given that you're going from object to string, really just use toString or toSQL() or something like that. Besides, if you designed it well and are using the right app, you can rename it later and just stick stuff in the comments on what it does.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say serialize and deserialize, instead of parse and ...

Answer (score 4):

I would go for ToString(), since you can usually chain-nest them (opposite functions, that let you pass from Class1 to Class2 and vice-versa)

```
DateTime.Parse( DateTime.Parse( myDate.ToString() ).ToString() );
```

Serialize() looks like a nice choice, but it already has an opposite in Deserialize().

In your specific scenario, as other pointed out, ToSql() is another good choice.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use render

```
> a = 'html': { 'head': {'title': 'My Page'}, 'body': { 'h1': 'Hello World', 'p': 'This is a Paragraph' } }

> b = render(a)

> console.log(b)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is a Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which is IMHO, the opposite to parse()

```
> c = parse(b)

{ 'html': {
    'head': {
        'title': 'My Page'
    }
    'body': {
        'h1': 'Hello World',
        'p': 'This is a Paragraph'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Generate, but tack on what you're generating, i.e. GenerateSQL()

Answer (score 3):

I voted for 'compose' but if you don't like that I would also suggest 'build'

Answer (score 3):

What about asSQL() or even more asQuery()?

Answer (score 3):

INHO Serialize, synthesize are good options. Also, as you have named parseQuery, i will go with codeQuery

Answer (score 3):

I usually use "parse" as a conversion method and, therefore, i can't find a opposite word for "convert". (you can't "deconvert" something, as "unconvert" is a type of conversion itself).

thinking this way, the best solution (for me) is having two "parse" methods that receive different arguments. Example (Java):

```
public class FooBarParser{

    public Foo parse(Bar bar);
    public Bar parse(Foo foo); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**deparse**

Deparse is to parse, as:

- decompile is to compile
- decompose is to compose
- deserialize is to serialize
- degroovy is to groovy :) ;)

Parsing / deparsing is not change of structure, but conversion. Precise conversion between equivalent text and abstract-syntax-tree formats, maintaining all relationships & structure.

"Compose" means change of structure, so is not quite right. It suggests combining from separate independent parts (usually for the first time).  Just as "decompose" suggests splitting into independent parts.  They change form, not just format.

A quick search show's the term's used within:

- Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html
- R: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_98.html
- Common Lisp: http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html#c-type-parse
- PostgreSQL: http://doxygen.postgresql.org/deparse_8c.html
- Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201883/
- Unix Korn Shell: http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/ksh/93tplus-p/deparse_8c.html

Comment: A quick Github Code search reveals that the term "deparse" has no widespread usage, see https://github.com/search?q=deparse - I think of "deparse" as a term from the R ecosystem. - For me the opposite of parsing is generating. In **parsing**, we have a sentence and a grammar as input and want to know what the syntactic structure and/or the semantics representation of the sentence is. In **generation**, we have a semantic representation and a grammar as input and want to find sentences that correspond to the semantic representation.

Answer (score 0):

writeQuery.
Parse is the act of reading it from a string and creating the object (let's say 'actual') representation.
The opposite would be writing the object into a string.

Answer (score 0):

`.GetSqlQuery()` would be my choice

Answer (score -6):

I believe the answer you're looking for is: "Don't parse SQL or assemble SQL in the first place. Use an Object/Relational Mapper and stop wasting your employer's money by solving problems that have already been solved for quite some time."

Comment: -1. You have no idea what he's doing. He might have a perfectly good reason for doing it. Not all applications are the same.

Comment: I must agree, I had recently a perfectly good reason to parse SQL that had nothing to do with ORM's (which I used in the project as well).

Comment: I'd love to hear this 'perfectly good reason'. No, actually I wouldn't. I could imagine if you were building a SQL IDE or something, but even then -- why are you building a SQL IDE when they are some heavy hitters in the market already?

Comment: Reason was basically we had to turn a query 'SELECT CustomerId FROM Customer' into something like 'SELECT <<field:25>> FROM <<table:76>>'. This is easy for basic select, very difficult for complex queries.

Comment: Please tell me how nHibernate would help me to do this?

Comment: Please tell me why you'd be doing that in the first place.